# .htaccess rewrite url issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I recently had a blog at www.andrewalaniz.com and I have moved it into a blog on my new business website www.effectusdigital.com.

The blog was hosted at blogspot, so to make things easier, I moved DNS to point it to my hosting account, and planned to handle everything thru mod rewrite and redirects.

If you go to www.andrewalaniz.com it correctly redirects (I had originally wanted it to redirect to /blog, but since I am having a duplicate content issue, I changed it)

The problem is Google has already indexed some of my pages both for effectusdigital.com and for andrewalaniz.com.  For example if you go to www.andrewalaniz.com/contact that is where it goes, it does not rewrite the url.

Here is what my htaccess file looks like(I have tried a number of variations to the code bleow):
Also, the only thing I am trying to accomplish here is to rewrite andrewalaniz.com to effectusdigital.com and return a 301.  The URIs are taken care of.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.andrewalaniz.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^andrewalaniz.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.effectusdigital.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Other than a small problem (the / before $1 is superfluous) I don't any problem with the mod-rewrite. You might want to make sure you don't have any wrong adress cached or something

Comment: Perhaps add a L to the last rule?  `[R=301,L]`

Comment: L is in there now.  See the comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is in your .htaccess, you do need the `/` before the `$1`

Adding the L would ensure that processing stops after this rule.

Below is a more concise version that will do the same thing

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  andrewalaniz.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.effectusdigital.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried it to no effect, and yes the / is there for correct canonicalization of my site.

Comment: @AndrewAlaniz With this soulution did none of the redirects work or just `/contact`? If the latter, you also have a folder called `contact` in your site?

Comment: Yes, that is my main problem at this point is the pages that exist at effectusdigital.com/pagename are being indexed at both effectusdigital.com and andrewalaniz.com, so yes /contact exists, but I only want it visible as effectusdigital.com

Comment: @AndrewAlaniz I meant that you have a physical directory in the root folder of you site called `contact` that is interfering with your url `/contact`. Let me know if that is correct

Comment: No that is not correct.  There is no directory, just a page at that url.

Comment: @AndrewAlaniz Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess besides these?

Comment: wordpress rules, cache rules which I clear out before testing, and some redirects.

Comment: some mod_deflate rules, some header rules, and some mime rules

Comment: @AndrewAlaniz put these new rules before any other rules

Comment: That did it.  I put them at the front and it fixed it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind: you've forgotten "`QSA`" and "`L`" directive, and you could apply your filter on one line instead of two:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((.*)\.)andrewalaniz.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.effectusdigital.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Once you've done this, google will see there's a definitive redirect, and will change its page results accordingly.

This is exactly what happenned to my old website `http://olivier.pons.free.fr` which is now `http://olivierpons.fr`. It took something like 10 days for google to register "properly" the change but it worked like a charm.

Edit: if it doesn't work try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((.*)\.)andrewalaniz.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.effectusdigital.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I currently have this in the .htaccess file.  if you go to andrewalaniz.com/contact or www.andrewalaniz.com/contact (for example) then it does not rewrite.  If you go to www.andrewalaniz.com it works fine.  If I can't get this working, I am just going to setup a separate hosting account for andrewalaniz.com and do it that way.

Comment: Try with `Options -Indexes -FollowSymlinks`